# GUI based on XML

Tags: c++, xml, qt, user-interface

I want to create a GUI (with Qt) based on a XML.
my XML will look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <boutons>
        <bouton name="bouton1" type="rotateur" pos_x="0" pos_y="0" />
        <bouton name="bouton2" type="poussoir" pos_x="0" pos_y="1" />
    </boutons>
```

for type rotateur, it will be a QDial;
for type poussoir, it will be a QPushButton.

(Pos_x & Pos_x is to put my button in a QGridLayout)

and there will be some other type in the future..

How would you do this ?

With a virtual class Button and classes derived from Button ?

(Sorry if my english is bad i'm trying my best :p )

Comment: I am not an expert for Qt but if I remember correctly Qt already uses XML files for GUI layout. You create GUI elements with editor and the IDE add appropriate entries to the XML file that describes the UI.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Y, that's why I'm asking, I was thinking the same, because the .ui is a XML... That's actually why I'm asking this question, there is maybe something in Qt which already do what I want...

Comment: when you want to use `qt` functionality, then use their format. look at the `ui` files and adapt to that layout

Comment: The thing here is that I don't want to use editor, because I want that if someone changes the XML, then it changes the GUI

Comment: I think you just need to dynamically load `.ui` files using the existing `Qt` functionality instead of rolling your own version of this.

Comment: Write in the proper format: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-ui-file-format.html

Comment: then you would really have to define the xml layout, write a parser for it and add the objects dynamically. BUT it might be possible using qml and load the qml files from the application directory

Comment: @drescherjm `.ui` files must be compiled, so there is no dynamically loading for a 'free' layout

Comment: Doesn't QUiLoader do that? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html

Comment: @drescherjm wow, missed that change

Comment: @drescherjm It looks cool, but is it possible to have the states of the button with that ? Because if I create a virtual class Button (then I have a QVector<Button>), and it's easy to have the states of the button, but with QUiLoader, I don't get it..

Comment: You can use signals and slots and/or possibly findChildren<QPushButton*>() in the parent class. You may want to use the objectName to aid with the find with findChildren<QPushButton*>("widgetName").